# Correct way of checking if a jwt token has expired in passport jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I have a created a middleware to check if the **jwt token** has expired.

For some reason the [TokenHasExpiredError](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#errors--codes) is not intercepted as an error in `passport.authenticate`.

Here's my middleware

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';

import { ApiError } from '../classes/error';

const authJwt = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', function (err, user, info) {
    // TokenExpiredError is not considered as an error?
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) {
      if (info.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
        return next(ApiError.jwtTokenExpired('Jwt Token Expired'));
      }
      return next(ApiError.unauthenticated('User is not authenticated'));
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
};

export default authJwt;
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. From the code above, why is `TokenExpiredError` or any other error not intercepted as an error.
2. What is the `info` parameter in the callback? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: 1. Post your TokenExpiredError code.

2. `Info` - . An optional info argument will be passed, containing additional details provided by the strategy's verify callback. (from the docs)

Comment: @Devious the tokenexpirederror is from the jsonwebtoken package used by passport-jwt behind the scenes. Basically, I set a expiresIn when creating a token using jwt.sign() method provided by jsonwebtoken